NotNullViolation when commiting after explicitly setting FK column for relationship
I am saving an object in SQl Alchemy using:
def save_reply(self, reply: PostgresReplyTable) -> PostgresReplyTable:
    """
    Save a reply

    Args:
        job: The job to save the reply for
        text: The text of the reply

    Returns:
        PostgresReplyTable: The reply
    """
    reply = self._session.merge(reply)
    self._session.commit()
    return reply

The debugger shows the used_prompt_id filed has a value:
/postgres_connector.py(444)save_reply()
-> self._session.commit()
(Pdb) reply
<database_sdk.models.reply.PostgresReplyTable object at 0x7fd3d0179240>
(Pdb) reply.used_prompt_id
2

Yet doing the commit I get the error:
(Pdb) n
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "used_prompt_id" of relation "reply" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, This is a reply to the job based on the use case requirements., d4e8e3e7-8a8c-4f2e-8e5e-0e2a7a3c9b0d, 2, null, null, null, null, 2024-06-10 11:59:40.913716, 2024-06-10 11:59:40.913724, 2024-06-10 11:59:40.254929).

[SQL: UPDATE reply SET used_prompt_id=%(used_prompt_id)s WHERE reply.reply_id = %(reply_reply_id)s]
[parameters: {'used_prompt_id': None, 'reply_reply_id': 1}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)
2

Debugging shows the value of the used_prompt_id field is there. I do not understand why the commit is failing
the reply object definition:
class PostgresReplyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "reply"
    reply_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=True)
    job_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("job.job_id"))
    use_case_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("use_case.id"))
    used_prompt_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("prompt.prompt_id"))
    feedback_rate: Mapped[Optional[int]]
    feedback_comment: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(Text)
    input_text: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(Text)
    job: Mapped["PostgresJobTable"] = relationship(back_populates="reply")  # type: ignore
    use_case: Mapped["PostgresUseCaseTable"] = relationship(back_populates="replies")  # type: ignore
    used_prompt: Mapped["PostgresPromptTable"] = relationship(back_populates="reply")
    processing_start_date: Mapped[Optional[datetime]]
    processing_end_date: Mapped[Optional[datetime]]
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(default=datetime.now())


Possibly related GitHub comment

Why are you using merge() here?  I think you want add() right?  Is it a new or existing reply?  Your docstring doesn't seem to make sense with the actual function definition.  Merging objects into the session can get complicated.

@IanWilson - Apparently they are trying to do an upsert. The DML statment is an UPDATE on an existing reply_id. (If they used .add() they would get a duplicate PK error.)

@GordThompson I guess I thought merge was for something completely different.  It can be very complicated to use.

It was a circular dependency. A reply has a job which has a use case which has a prompt which has a reply. i removed the last prompt - reply relaion and it works now.
